# Словари различных авторов на хостинге narod.ru

Tags: предложение

Когда **Yandex** запускал проект **narod.ru** (бесплатный хостинг сайтов с ограниченным функционалом, т.е. только **html**, **css** и **js** и ничего более) то он сразу же шел с некоторым количеством рекламы, ее было немного, и она не раздражала.

Когда проект **narod.ru** был передан в ведение **uCoz** - на нем появилось столько рекламы, что часто за ней не видно основного контента. Такая реклама никакой прибыли владельцам сайтов на **narod.ru** не несет.

Также в тело самих **html** страниц внедряется дополнительный код от самих хостеров.

---

**Пример одного из таких сайтов:** [ФОРМЫ ИМЕН СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫХ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm)

---

Есть предложение перенести словари с **narod.ru** на **github.io**. Какие от этого плюсы?

- Полное отсутствие рекламы.
- Лишний код не внедряется в тело страниц.

---

В случае заинтересованности готов помочь с переездом. На общественных началах.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше предложение, я попробую выяснить, целесообразно ли оно в данный момент, и напишу позже.

Comment: Отличная идея! Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем именно ваш план? Что вы предлагаете, какую бы помощь хотели получить от сообщества?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема засилья рекламы – одна из самых неприятных. Тем не менее нужно понимать, что за ней может стоять заработок, на который обеспечивается существование того или иного сайта. Особенно это касается сайтов-словарей, которые, к примеру, могут производить отчисления авторам.